# Href link on page does not show up in jsp

Tags: jsp, href

I have a url in my jsp page which gets formed as below :

```
 <% if (policyInfoViewBean.hasValuableArticlesCoverage()) { %>
    <tr>
      <td height="25" valign="top" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td height="25" valign="top" align="right" class="rightNav" background="<%= imagePath %>/r_fill.gif">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="rightNav" background="<%= imagePath %>/r_fill.gif">
            <% if (policyInfoViewBean.isPersonalArticlesFloater()) { %>
                    <a href="<%= actionString %>POL11&<%=SessionKeys.CPI_POLICY_NUMBER%>=<%= policy.getPolicyNumber()%>" class="rightNav">Personal Articles Floater</a></td>
            <% } else { %>
                    <a href="<%= actionString %>POL11&<%=SessionKeys.CPI_POLICY_NUMBER%>=<%= policy.getPolicyNumber()%>" class="rightNav">Valuable Articles</a></td>
            <% } %>
      <td class="rightNav" background="<%= imagePath %>/r_fill.gif">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
```

This condition is fulfilled and it enters the else part but it does not show me the url while I 'm running on local.

Please advice.

Comment: can u please tell what is the expected url & what actionString,SessionKeys.CPI_POLICY_NUMBER,policy.getPolicyNumber() results in

Comment: It just gets the policy number from the policy bean

Comment: if u put ur backend code i will try to figure out

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to Print the values of the url to the log to be sure that they contains valid values and check the log for exceptions

```
<% System.out.println(actionString+"POL11&"+SessionKeys.CPI_POLICY_NUMBER+"="+policy.getPolicyNumber());
%>
```